# I have a question abouut the ldap get the memberOf value

Tags: c#, .net

When I try to get the ture value， but this code always output the false.
How should I modify this code?

```
foreach (Object memberof in rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memberOf"])
{
string str1 = memberof.ToString() + " | ";
string str2 = "CN=Allow,CN=Users,DC=A1,DC=A2,DC=A3";
if (str1.contains(str2))
    lblVPN.Text = "VPN Access : Allow";
else
    lblVPN.Text = "VPN Access : Denied";
}
```

Comment: Did you debug and check if the value you expect in memberOf property is coming or its different from what you have given in str2

Comment: Yeap, I'm sure the str2 in the str list.

Comment: The code looks correct and as per your comment it is always going into the false branch (access denied). Not sure why you say that str2 in in str1, the code shows it not.

Comment: What is the value in `str1`?

Comment: I have check this list in the LDAP, and the memberOf contacins CN=Allow,CN=Users,DC=A1,DC=A2,DC=A3,but when I Debug this code, it show me denied. It's very strange. And when I output ‘memberof.ToString() + " | "’ this code, I can see str2 in the outcome.

Comment: str1 = CN=Allow,CN=Users,DC=A1,DC=A2,DC=A3|CN=Allow1,CN=Users,DC=A1,DC=A2,DC=A3|CN=Allow2,CN=Users,DC=A1,DC=A2,DC=A3|CN=Allow3,CN=Users,DC=A1,DC=A2,DC=A3|CN=Allow4,CN=Users,DC=A1,DC=A2,DC=A3|CN=Allow5,CN=Users,DC=A1,DC=A2,DC=A3

Comment: Please add any additional information directly to the question instead of using comments.